# Reading data from db and showing progress indicator at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, progress-bar

I need help with showing progress indicator while reading the data from the database. An example that I have done is interrupted in the middle of a new thread and continues to run a main thread. When the main thread is carried out until the end, then the execution of another thread continues. What is missing in this?

```
private void loadingData() throws InterruptedException{

    prgIndLogin.setVisible(true);
    prgIndLogin.setProgress(-1);

    Thread newThrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            try {
                KorisnikJpaController korCont = new KorisnikJpaController(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LawOfficeV2PU"));
                EntityManager em = korCont.getEntityManager();

                logedUser = (Korisnik) em.createNamedQuery("Korisnik.findByUsernameAndPassword")
                                        .setParameter("usernamekor", tbxUsername.getText())
                                        .setParameter("passwordkor", passField.getText())
                                        .getSingleResult();

                em.close();
                status=true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                status = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        prgIndLogin.setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    newThrd.start();

}
```

Comment: tbh if login requires a progress bar, you want to fix the login code... apart from that, unclear what you are trying to do & how the behavior differs from what you expect

Comment: I'm trying to show progress indicator while reading data from the database.If field "status" is true allow verification of the existence of user else show warning... in the above case realize the connection to the database but does not execute query immediately, but after the execution of main thread returns and execute thread. I want to above method immediately commit to the end that i might get information ....